# Find Long running Query Oracle DB along with start and end time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Hi i tried to find the long running query along with DB instance name , Node name, but I'm not sure Sometimes node name and DB instance name are same.

Please check the query I used

```
select 
A.SQL_ID,
B.MACHINE AS SQL_ID_INSTANCE,
CASE 
WHEN C.MACHINE LIKE '%NODE%' Then 'NODE TRIGGER'
WHEN B.MACHINE LIKE '%DB_INSTANCE%' Then 'DB_INSTANCE_TRIGGER'
END AS FIRED_FROM_WHICH_INSTANCE ,
CASE 
WHEN C.MACHINE LIKE '%NODE%' Then 'NODE TRIGGER'
WHEN B.MACHINE LIKE '%DB_INSTANCE%' Then 'DATABASE' 
END AS RAN_ON_WHICH_NODE,
C.MACHINE AS NODE_NAME,
B.MODULE AS APPLICATION,
B.PROGRAM AS DB_INSTANCE_MACHINE,
B.SQL_OPNAME AS OPERATION
from 
V$SQL A JOIN gv$active_session_history B ON A.SQL_ID=B.SQL_ID
JOIN dba_hist_active_sess_history C ON C.SQL_ID=B.SQL_ID
WHERE C.SAMPLE_TIME LIKE '%14-JUN-23%';
```